# passing jIntArray gives Unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing an Android app which communicates through jni with C++ (not C). I was able to successfully pass a jstring, so the setup works, but now I want to pass a jintarray. However, the code returns an Unsatisfied Link Error on the native method, so I think I am not properly returning a jintarray.

```
extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_example_optimuse_MainActivity_generate(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jintArray arr);

};

JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_example_optimuse_MainActivity_generate(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){

    int mymusic[6];
    mymusic[0]=60;
    mymusic[1]=64;
    mymusic[2]=67;
    mymusic[3]=72;
    mymusic[4]=67;
    mymusic[5]=64;

    jintArray jmymusic = env->NewIntArray(6);

    env->SetIntArrayRegion(jmymusic, 0, 6, mymusic);

    return jmymusic;
}
```

And I call this in java like this:

```
int[] music = generate();
```

I think I am doing something basic wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Your function definition differs from the declaration (it has one argument less).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael  OMG! You are right. This got cut off on my screen because of resolution ;-) Must have been there from all the testing I did with importing arrays.

Thanks a million, of course it should be

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_example_optimuse_MainActivity_generate(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz);

};
```